# Prestashop export SQL

Tags: sql, prestashop

I need help in exporting attributes in `Prestashop 1.7.6`

Attribute are "`Velikost`", "`Materiál`" and "`Věková kategorie`" "[image]

Price is with no tax. How add price WITH tax?

My code:

```
SELECT
ps_product.id_product AS id,
ps_product_lang.name AS title,
ps_product_lang.description AS description,
ps_product_lang.description_short as description_short,
 =====there need attributes =======
ps_product.price AS price1,
ps_product.show_price AS price2,
ps_product_lang.id_product AS brand,
ps_product_lang.id_product AS gtin,
ps_product_lang.id_product AS identifier_exists,


ps_product.id_category_default,
ps_product.active,
ps_product_lang.link_rewrite,
ps_category_lang.link_rewrite,
 
CONCAT("/index.php?id_product=", ps_product.id_product, "/","&rewrite=" ,ps_product_lang.link_rewrite,"&controller=product") AS link

FROM
ps_product

INNER JOIN ps_product_lang ON ps_product.id_product = ps_product_lang.id_product
INNER JOIN ps_category_lang ON ps_product.id_category_default = ps_category_lang.id_category
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: You can't do all what you want with a single query. To get data from products and combinations, and right final prices, it's needed a complex script. To be able to develop your own exporting tool, you need to know a lot about PrestaShop, including code and database scheme. An alternative is to use an yet existing tool, so versatile, as PrestaExport.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Can I want more querys - For example only "velikost". How i do it?

Comment: You need a well knowledge of PrestaShop's database tables, and their relations. However, you ask for getting only "velikost" attribute, this can be another question, so I asked myself and here you are: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73941822/how-to-get-from-prestashop-database-a-list-of-product-combinations-related-to-a/73941823#73941823

Comment: José Carlos, i'm very THANK YOU! :)