# How to get from PrestaShop database a list of product combinations related to a certain attribute with a single query?

Tags: mysql, sql, prestashop

We are in **PrestaShop**.
We want to export product combinations related to a certain attribute.
And we hope to do it using just a single query.

So, for a given attribute, identified by its ID (that will be `id_attribute_group` from table `product_attribute`), we want to list all product combinations that actually use that attribute.

The values we want to extract are:

- Product ID
- Combination ID
- Product name
- Product enabled (or not)
- Combination reference
- Attribute value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, this task requires a well knowledge of PrestaShop database tables, and their relations. Once you have learn enough about that, you will be able to face the task.

So, these are the tables and the fields we will need to use:

| Table | Fields |
| --- | --- |
| attribute | id_attribute, id_attribute_group |
| attribute_lang | id_attribute, id_lang, name |
| product | id_product, active |
| product_lang | id_product, id_lang, name |
| product_attribute | id_product, id_product_attribute, reference |
| product_attribute_combination | id_attribute, id_product_attribute |

Hint: It's quite easy to see relations between those tables because of the same name fields.

And now it's time to build our query!

As mentioned in the question body, we will have a given `id_attribute_group`, that identifies the attribute wich related product combinations we want to export. Let's say this value is `1`.

Because we will extract some language related data, we need a fixed value, this is the ID
of the language we want (that will be `id_lang` from table `lang`). Let's say this value is `1` as well.

As I'm writing the query literally (not using a program language), I need to know the tables prefix used in the target PrestaShop. Let's say this value is `ps_` (the default one).

Good. Now we can start to write down our query, starting with the `SELECT` part, containing the fields whose values ​​we want to obtain:

```
SELECT
    p.id_product, pa.id_product_attribute, pl.name, p.active, pa.reference, al.name AS attribute_value
```

Now the `FROM` part, containing the tables where the fields are from, using `JOIN` to specify relations and filtering:

```
FROM ps_product p
JOIN ps_product_lang pl ON pl.id_product = p.id_product AND pl.id_lang = 1
JOIN ps_product_attribute pa ON pa.id_product = p.id_product
JOIN ps_product_attribute_combination pac ON pac.id_product_attribute = pa.id_product_attribute
JOIN ps_attribute_lang al ON al.id_attribute = pac.id_attribute AND al.id_lang = 1
JOIN ps_attribute a ON a.id_attribute = pac.id_attribute AND a.id_attribute_group = 1
```

We can order the results. Let's do it by `id_product` and `id_product_attribute`:

```
ORDER BY p.id_product, pa.id_product_attribute
```

Finally, for the first time it's a good idea to limit the number of results, that way we avoid a slow and high consuming query (that can be a headhache if there are thousands of combinations). We can enlarge or even remove this limit later.

```
LIMIT 100
```

### And here is the full query:

```
SELECT
    p.id_product, pa.id_product_attribute, pl.name, p.active, pa.reference, al.name AS attribute_value
FROM ps_product p
JOIN ps_product_lang pl ON pl.id_product = p.id_product AND pl.id_lang = 1
JOIN ps_product_attribute pa ON pa.id_product = p.id_product
JOIN ps_product_attribute_combination pac ON pac.id_product_attribute = pa.id_product_attribute
JOIN ps_attribute_lang al ON al.id_attribute = pac.id_attribute AND al.id_lang = 1
JOIN ps_attribute a ON a.id_attribute = pac.id_attribute AND a.id_attribute_group = 1
ORDER BY p.id_product, pa.id_product_attribute
LIMIT 100
```

**Remember**:

- To get combinations related to a different attribute, just use its ID instead of `1` in `a.id_attribute_group = 1`.
- To get language related values in a different language, just use its ID instead of `1` in `pl.id_lang = 1` and `al.id_lang = 1`.
- If your PrestaShop installation tables prefix is not `ps_`, just replace all `ps_` with the right one.

##### Just a last thing to say

To get data from products **and** combinations from PrestaShop it can be a hard job. I have shown an example of how to get combinations related to just one attribute. It will get harder if you need to export values from **all** attributes. Also it get harder if you want to export single products as well as combinations, and if you want to extract data that differs from the parent product to their combinations. Also it get harder if you want to export right final values, as prices (tax includes, etc.).

It will be impossible using just one query. It will be needed a **complex** script. To be able to develop your own exporting tool, you need to know a lot about PrestaShop, including code and database scheme. An alternative is to use a yet existing tool, so versatile, as PrestaExport.